# 外部キーを利用したタグのAND検索の方法

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQLを使っています。条件「タグ"青"かつタグ"大"と紐付けられたポスト」の検索方法がわかりません。

以下のようなテーブルを作成しました。

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tagpost (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  post_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id)
);
```

データは以下のように挿入しました。

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM post;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM tag;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  8 | 青   |
|  9 | 大   |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM tagpost;
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      8 |
|  2 |       1 |      9 |
|  3 |       2 |      8 |
+----+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

この時、「タグ"青"またはタグ"大"と紐付けられたポスト」を検索する場合は以下のSQLで出来たのですが、

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM post
  INNER JOIN tagpost ON tagpost.post_id = post.id
  INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
  WHERE tag.name = '青' OR tag.name = '大'
  ;
```

別の条件で、「タグ"青"かつタグ"大"と紐付けられたポスト」を検索する方法がわかりません。
わかる人いたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 試していると思いますが、`OR`ではなく`AND`で実行した結果はどうなのでしょうか？

Comment: ANDで実行した結果はemptyでした。条件にマッチするPOSTがありませんでした。

Comment: そこをANDにした場合、tag.nameが"青"かつ"大"となるレコードを検索することになります。そのようなレコードは存在しえないので必ずemptyとなります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少し分かりにくくはなりますが、拡張性を考えるのであれば、こちらが良いかもしれません。

```
SELECT * FROM post p
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) from tagpost
    INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
    WHERE p.id = tagpost.post_id AND tag.name IN ('青', '大'))
```

tag.nameが'青'か'大'でのタグの件数を集計して、その件数が2件(検索するタグの種類数)に一致するか、という条件です。
IN句の中と2という件数を条件に応じて変更するだけで済みます。
たぶんパフォーマンスも良いのではないかと。
検証していないのでご参考程度にどうぞ。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。こちらの方法でもテスト中です。

Comment: 目的とする出力を得られました。ありがとうございました。
user17014氏の回答にベストアンサーを付けましたが、その後user17014氏からコメントを頂いたのでそれを参考にKONDO氏の回答に、また、パフォーマンスが良いということなので、こちらの回答にベストアンサーを付けさせていただきたいと思います。
テストは目視によるテストを行いました。参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみにパフォーマンスについては未検証です:-)

Answer (score 0):

以下のようなSQLで行けると思います。

```
SELECT * FROM post AS p
INNER JOIN
(SELECT tagpost.post_id FROM tagpost
  INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
  WHERE tag.name = '青') blue
  ON blue.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT tagpost.post_id FROM tagpost
  INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
  WHERE tag.name = '大') big
  ON big.post_id = p.id
```

考え方は、「青」のタグを持つPOSTの一覧をサブクエリで作成し、
同様に「大」のタグを持つPOSTの一覧をサブクエリで作成します。
その両方に内部結合できるもの、すなわち両方の一覧に存在しているものを、POSTより抽出します。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。現在回答いただいたSQLでテスト中です。

Comment: 回答いただいたSQLで目的とする出力が得られました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

こういう考え方もありますね。

```
SELECT * FROM post p
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * from tagpost
    INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
    WHERE tag.name = '青' AND p.id = tagpost.post_id)
  AND
  EXISTS (SELECT * from tagpost
    INNER JOIN tag ON tagpost.tag_id = tag.id
    WHERE tag.name = '大' AND p.id = tagpost.post_id)
```

nameが"青"のtagが存在し、かつtag.nameが"大"のものが存在するpostという条件を取っています。
パフォーマンスや条件が増えたときにどうするかは別途考慮する必要があるかもしれませんが、分かりやすくはあります。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。こちらもサブクエリなんですね。サブクエリを使ったことがないのでサブクエリを使う方法が頭に浮かびませんでしたX(

Comment: EXISTSという方法もありましたね。今回はデータの結合が目的ではないのでこちらの方が意味合いとしては適切だと思います。

Comment: こちらの方法でもテスト中です。

Comment: 目的とする出力を得られました。ありがとうございました。